# Scrolling div by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem and I dont know how to solve it...

I have divs on a page, which are all of a class "dailyComments".

Underneath each of these divs I have two images with arrows - up and down (classes scrollDown and scrollUp). My goal is for the user to be able to click one of these arrows and the above div would scroll down/up.

I tried the prev() function, but for some reason it does not work. So for example, for the scroll down I have:

```
$('.scrollDown').click(function() {
   $(this).prev(".dailyComments").scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() + 25);
});
```

I also tried for example this:

```
$(this).prev(".dailyComments").hide()
```

and it did work, it hide the preceding dailyComments div. But with the scroll it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your HTML so we can see the layout in the DOM?

Comment: Why are you using `this`? `this` refers to the button in this case. and `prev` may not necessarily be the target `div`. Better, just call the scroll directly on the `div` -- `$("#divId").scrollTop...`

Comment: HTML is need for this buddy...

Comment: Because the divs dont have unique IDs, there is hundreds of them so I would have to create a "click" functoin for each one.

Comment: In that case you need to respond [to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607405/scrolling-div-by-jquery#comment53066022_32607405) ^^^.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
var dcom = $(this).prev(".dailyComments");
dcom.scrollTop(dcom.offset().top + 25);
```

Comment: you should share the html as well.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is

```
 $("div").scroll(function(){
    $("span").text(x += 1);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

OK I solved it by giving each DIV a unique ID